# Update data fetched by ajax through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php page which calls another php page to fetch the database data. The database data is successfully fetched via ajax.

Now I want to update the data fetched in the form of table via update link in the table itself. The issue is that if I call the `id of the edit button inside document.ready` in  the parent page. It is unable to find the id as the table loads only when some data is inserted in table.

Architecture goes like,

> Page 1 ----> Step 1 (Add data to database via ajax)
>
> Step 2 (Fetch the same data in table format via ajax)
>                        suppose the ID if the submit button is edit. This ID is only
>                        initialized when table is loaded.

The problem is I want to edit the tale on click of edit button. I am not figure out where exactly to place the ajax code for it. If I place it in parent page, it is unable to find the id till the data is loaded.

Please help on how should I edit the data of table loaded via ajax.

Comment: I was going to say lol

Comment: also the html document needs a doc type, head and body, like any valid html

Comment: i dont think that echo will crate a problem...but any ways still the same..

Comment: ok let me add a doc type and check

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Start trouble shooting by going section by section until you discover the error

Comment: @user2067005 I have done almost every thing...I am saying you na that if I type "test email" as body of email the email goes....

Comment: Updated the above code add doctype but still the email does not go...

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala you have so much $msg info that it's hard to sort the error out without cutting the msg into pieces and seeing what sends and what doesn't send

Comment: You could test with just the first few lines. If that works add a few lines... etc. When it stops working then you got the problem line(s). B.t.w. small typo in the headers... '$headerss' for the MIME header.

Comment: the body tags next to each other was a typo correct?

Comment: put `<table>` in `<body>`.

Comment: updated still email does not go..

Comment: @Rik corrected the headers typo but still the same...email does not go...

Comment: remove your parentheses in the includes. The syntax is: include 'filename';

Comment: Do you need those 4 include lines at the top of your php? You don't use mime encoding and the mail function works here without includes.

Comment: @Rik No I require that includes as the email headers and footers are added directly from database...also tried removing mime but sill it is not getting fired..

Comment: updated the above code with actual code that I am using..

Comment: you still haven't removed the parentheses in your includes

Comment: Also, one test you can do, is creating a basic function in mail.php, that echo's out something, the try calling it your code above. This is just to make sure the other php-files is called correctly

Comment: Did you original code that you posted HERE work for you? If not, then you should not change it to you real code because we can't run that. I removed the includes because i don't have that source and it worked. We don't know if your Mail.php has an alternative mail function that screws up the $msg.

Comment: @Rik updated the code for you to test it.

Comment: @Nilzone-I have removed all includes in the updated code above but still does not work.

Comment: Previous code already worked without the include lines. Tested with this new code and this worked perfectly. Message echo's on screen and below that i get "mailer_sent" (And i get my mail). What do you get? "mailer not sent"?

Comment: Only thing i can think of is your sendmail blocks your message because it thinks its spam with all those images. Could/can you check your sendmail.log's on your php-server?

Comment: Its text block that is not sending the email. But why will the text block stop email from getting fired?? Cant understand.

Comment: Because if you have a spam-plugin with your sendmail config then sendmail can deny you to send mail. If your body contains lots of images sendmail (or spam-plugin) could deny your mail. A simple "Hello" would go through. So, check your sendmail.log's. There you should find the reason for the mail not sending.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your php.ini file configured correctly to send email.  It could be an issue with the mail server you're using .  Reconfigure to use something like gmail that you know works.   Send a simple email from this client so that you have a baseline that you're starting from.   Then, switch over to you're existing client.  Send the mail again.  Does it work?  If so, start adding in your logic bit by bit testing each time.   It should be pretty clear as to what's breaking.

Comment: a simple message "hi" is emailed perfectly. Its only when I am adding my message its not working.

Comment: OK, so there's your baseline.  Now, start adding in your logic piece by piece as I suggested.  It'll be obvious what breaks it.

Comment: Its text block that is not sending the email. But why will the text block stop email from getting fired?? Cant understand.

Comment: As someone else mentioned, I'm not sure why you're echoing out $msg when you assing it.  Also, try output buffering instead of assigning your message to the $msg var.  Use ob_start & ob_get_clean.

Answer (score 0):

Like i said in one of my comments:

Because a simple "Hello" message is getting out i think you sendmail (of spam-plugin in sendmail) is blocking your bigger message. Your big messages contain images etc.

If i sent the message over the internet i get the following headers from SpamAssassin.

```
X-Spam-Report: 
    *  0.1 FORGED_RCVD_HELO Received: contains a forged HELO
    * -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
    *  2.1 DEAR_SOMETHING BODY: Contains 'Dear (something)'
    *  4.2 MIME_BAD_ISO_CHARSET BODY: MIME character set is an unknown ISO
    *      charset
    *  0.5 HTML_TITLE_UNTITLED BODY: HTML title contains "Untitled"
    *  0.5 HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_02 BODY: HTML has a low ratio of text to image
    *      area
    * -2.6 BAYES_00 BODY: Bayesian spam probability is 0 to 1%
    *      [score: 0.0000]
    *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
    *  0.0 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
    *  0.0 MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY 'Content-Type' found without required MIME
    *      headers
    *  0.3 HTML_TITLE_SUBJ_DIFF HTML_TITLE_SUBJ_DIFF
```

Depending on the configuration of your sendmail/spam filter this could cause the problem.

So, check your server logs if you can   for why the mail function from php blocks your mail.